# QUnit+PhantomJS: Ajax success handler not called in grunt using qunit with PhantomJS

Tags: ajax, gruntjs, phantomjs, qunit

To be able to test one function which needs to make on async request to a server i used the following asyncTest call within my gruntfile.js using qunit.

```
asyncTest("country", function() {
  Catalog.Country.load( function() {
    ok( Utils.objectsize( Catalog.Country.list)>0, "country list has content");
    equal( Catalog.Country.getCountryNameFromCode('US'), 'USA', "USA for code US exists");
    equal( Utils.objectsize( Catalog.Country.getStatesForCountry('US')), 51, "USA has 51 states");
    equal( Utils.objectsize( Catalog.Country.getStatesForCountry('US', 1)), 51, "USA has 51 states (with keys)");
    start();
  });
});
```

This code is from my test HTML file which runs fine on the browser. All 4 assertions are OK. But using grunt with this simple qunit block:

```
qunit: {
  main: [ 'tests/country.html' ]
}
```

ends with the following debug output:

```
[D] ["phantomjs","qunit.begin"]
[D] ["phantomjs","onLoadFinished","success"]
[D] ["phantomjs","qunit.moduleStart",null]
[D] ["phantomjs","qunit.testStart","country"]
[D] ["phantomjs","onResourceRequested",{"headers":[{"name":"Origin","value":"file://"},{"name":"User-Agent","value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.7 Safari/534.34"},{"name":"Accept","value":"application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"}],"id":5,"method":"GET","time":"2014-03-14T14:54:47.201Z","url":"http://localhost:1021/json.fly?a=country&lang=en"}]
[D] ["phantomjs","onResourceReceived",{"contentType":"application/json","headers":[{"name":"Date","value":"Fri, 14 Mar 2014 14:54:47 GMT"},{"name":"Server","value":"Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)"},{"name":"Set-Cookie","value":"ossess=localhost_AUA_AT_de_0C1ECE3755F7367CF48F207C53E0DB61; path=/; HttpOnly"},{"name":"Access-Control-Allow-Origin","value":"*"},{"name":"Transfer-Encoding","value":"chunked"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"application/json"},{"name":"X-Cache","value":"MISS from proxy"},{"name":"X-Cache-Lookup","value":"MISS from proxy:3128"},{"name":"Via","value":"1.0 proxy (squid/3.0.STABLE25)"},{"name":"Proxy-Connection","value":"close"}],"id":5,"redirectURL":null,"stage":"end","status":200,"statusText":"OK","time":"2014-03-14T14:54:47.348Z","url":"http://localhost:1021/json.fly?a=country&lang=en"}]
[D] ["phantomjs","fail.timeout"]

>> PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing QUnit start() call.
Warning: 1/1 assertions failed (0ms) Use --force to continue.
```

I put some logging on the json API, the request is really coming in and json response is returned. And as i said on browser it works. But not on console with grunt.
What is wrong here? The success handler of jquery's ajax call of my Catalog.Country.load function is not called even if the request succeeds as you can see in the debug output, it shows STATUS:200 from apache and my log in the backend also shows data is returned. Here is the content of my Catalog.Country.load function which handles the callback.

```
load: function(callback) {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'http://localhost:1021/json.fly?a=country&lang=en',
      success: $.proxy( function( data) {
        this.list = data; // store result in local list var
        if( callback && callback.call) {
          callback.call(this); // call the callback function to inform about success
        }
      }, this)
    });
  }
```

**UPDATE:**
I updated the qunit block in gruntfile to disable web-security for phantomjs, so it allows cross-domain, i hope that was the reason, but still problem remains:

```
qunit: {
  options : {
    '--web-security': false,
    '--local-to-remote-url-access': true
  },
  main: [ 'tests/country.html' ]
}
```

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:**
You see localhost being used but instead i was using some domain, so it was cross-domain. changing it to localhost as above, worked. but still i need to use remote domain for testing or at least same domain but another port. so using web-security option in qunit still doesn't help, seems that phantomjs is ignoring cross-domain setting web-security and local-to-remote-url-access. Why that?

Comment: I also had the same problem (cross domain allow access one ), but after setting '--web-security': false  its working fine

Comment: depends, it does not solve for linux systems, only windows. Maybe it's how the dash dash params are passed and/or escaped in linux CLI?